# Finding standard deviation of an image

Tags: matlab, standard-deviation

Firstly, I want to find standard deviation of this image:

[image]

Secondly, I want to find standard deviation of all lines in the image.

But at the first step, somethings going wrong and I see this:

```
>> A = imread('C:\Users\PC\Desktop\deneme.jpg');
>> std (A);
Error using var (line 65)
First argument must be single or double.

Error in std (line 38)
y = sqrt(var(varargin{:}));

line 65: error(message('MATLAB:var:integerClass'));
line 38: y = sqrt(var(varargin{:}));
```

How can I solve this problem and what is the code of finding standard deviation of all lines in this image?

Answer (score 5):

The error is very explicit:

> First input argument must be single or double.

This happens because `A` is of type `uint8`. The input to `std` has to be floating point (`single` or `double`).

So: **convert to `double`**, and optionally divide by `255` to **normalize** values to the interval between `0` and `1`:

```
std(double(A)/255)
```

Note that the above gives the standard deviation of each column. If you want the stantard deviation of the image considered as a whole, **linearize** to a column vector first:

```
std(double(A(:))/255)
```